# is 指関節{しかんせつ} a "normal" japanese word or a rare technical one?

Tags: words

I was doing my vocab training and added a few body parts.

Then I noticed that [the word I had found in the English Wiktionary for "knuckle"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%87%E9%96%A2%E7%AF%80) seems to be untypable with my Windows Japanese IME.

This made me wonder if it's yet another case of learners "using too much kanji", etc. Is this a rare or unusual word, a word usually written in kana, or just a mistake in Wiktionary or of my own making?

Comment: Are you sure it's not ゆびかんせつ?

Comment: @ZhenLin: If so then that's definitely means the answer is a mistake in Wiktionary. Click on - I made it a link.

Comment: Here http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%87#Readings it says it's read ゆびかんせつ...

Comment: @Chocolate: Some entries of this kind are just copied and pasted from other parts of Wiktionary to add useful cross references, in the expectation that the place they're copying from has been checked, and that if not, spreading the mistake around will help it get noticed and fixed. In fact I do that myself on Wiktionary. This is one example of the many many ways in which Wiktionary potentially contains many potential mistakes. Potentially (-: Also the compound list entry you found could have been added before the main entry was changed ...

Comment: Oh, I am not sure whether or not ゆびかんせつ is the correct reading...

Comment: Anatomical termとしては「しかんせつ」と読むのが正解です。ただし普通の日本人はこう発音されても理解できないと思います。医学関係者以外がこの漢字を見れば、恐らく「ゆびかんせつ」と読む可能性が高いし、それで間違いではないと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in daily conversation it would be [指]{ゆび}の関節. 指関節 will sound technical.

EDIT: I think both ゆびかんせつ and しかんせつ can be used, but I'm not 100% sure. As for 指の[節]{ふし}, this isn't technical and can be used in daily language but I think it's a bit more uncommon and sounds a tiny bit archaic.